# Is this JavaScript optimization or not?

Tags: javascript, v8, spidermonkey, chakra

Can someone explain me what are the differences between those two functions below?

I'm wondering if JavaScript engines do some kind of nano-optimizations here.

```js
function withoutVar() {                                                                                                                   
  return 'stackoverflow';                                                                                                                    
}
function withVar() {
  var result = 'stackoverflow';
  return result;
}
var a = withoutVar();
var b = withVar();
```

Comment: i think there is no real difference, the variable get's cleaned up after the return and it will have practically no effect on the execution-speed. You are just saving one needless var.

Comment: Both do the same thing. No closures were introduced. No "lost references". You just added a few more characters to the code and that's about it.

Comment: ["This brings to mind a Bill Murray quote from Meatballs: It just doesn't matter! It just doesn't matter!"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that your function `withVar` causes the implementation to access the underlaying *Activation Object* respectively *Lexical Environment Record*. So technically, this function will run slower, but we are not even talking about *micro optimizations*, more like *nano optimizations*.

Some browsers might indeed optimize that code into the direct `return` statement for `withVar`. *Webkit* or at least *Chrome* with their *V8 engine* are good candidates for that. Either way, again, this is entirely trivial and you should not be concerned about run-time performance here.

[JSPerf benchmark](http://jsperf.com/sdfjklnsdjkfsdfsd)

<sup>Difference on my machine (Chrome) is about `0.32%` on ~7.000.000 calls.</sup>

---

The only argument I would consider to buy on stuff like this is, that the former function works with less *characters*. In that way, you can optimize your filesize and reduce traffic over the wire (but even then, we would have to optimize such statements on many instances before it really comes into play)

Answer (score 7):

Some engines may perform such an optimisation. The [Google Closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) certainly does so:

```
function withVar(){return"stackoverflow"}var a=withVar();
```

There will be virtually no difference in speed, but the "optimised" version is shorter (and therefore quicker for the client to download). Here's the results of [a benchmark](http://jsperf.com/flatten-return-string):

[image]

You can see that the "flat" version (without the variable declaration) is marginally faster (but look at the operations per second - this is an optimisation that's not even worth thinking about in terms of speed).

Comment: Which benchmark did you do James?

Comment: @FrançoisB. - I'm not sure what you mean. I've linked to the test case on http://jsperf.com in the answer.

Comment: At least for v8 you are running jsperf in a way that disables optimizations. See here http://jsperf.com/flatten-return-string/2 - over 2x faster and equal speed as expected.